# Embed youtube to ebay without iframe - IE issue

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I have this code to embed a youtube video to a store page:

```
<object height="300" width="400">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/C0DPdy98e4c?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/C0DPdy98e4c?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="300" width="400">
</object>
```

Although this works well almost all other browsers, Internet Explorer (edge at least) just shows this instead of video:

[image: Empty box on IE edge]

Ebay does not allow Iframes which is why I would need to find an alternative solution to my problem.

So my question is:
Has anyone a solution that allows me to embed youtube video to ebay page without using a iframe that also works with Internet Explorer? Or at least send me to correct direction?

Apologies for not being able to provide JSFiddle or similar, embed code does not render.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it seems this worked on IE edge and all other browsers we wanted:

```
<object width="400" height="300" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c/?rel=0&amp;showsearch=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;version=3&amp;modestbranding=1">
</object>
```

Notice, no params included.

I found the solution here (in deprecated section, at the bottom): [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

Please let me know if you can find better solution.

Comment: Does not work: https://www.ebay.de/itm/323634783404    
You can see it in the preview but not after editing and publishing.

Comment: They have since changed their CSP policy as I can see this in my console when I go to your link:
Refused to load plugin data from 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/KPRofwUoMxc' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'none'".

Answer (score 1):

Try using HTML5 to add the video, this works a treat!

See this test item I did a while back:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Very-Clearance-Test-Item-Do-not-purchase-/110817518370?hash=item19cd3d2322

it uses this code:

```
<video poster="http://media.very.co.uk/v/very/B494P_SP132_10_4D6FFc?" class="vjs-tech" id="Video1" preload="auto" src="http://media.very.co.uk/v/sd/B494P_SP132_10_4D6FFc/p_webm_576x768" autoplay="autoplay" loop="">
         <source data-quality-label="High" data-bitrate="2012" data-res="High" src="http://media.very.co.uk/v/sd/B494P_SP132_10_4D6FFc/p_mp4_576x768" type="video/mp4">          
         <source data-quality-label="Medium" data-bitrate="1549" data-res="Medium" src="http://media.very.co.uk/v/sd/B494P_SP132_10_4D6FFc/p_mp4_500x667" type="video/mp4">
         <source data-quality-label="Low" data-bitrate="909" data-res="Low" src="http://media.very.co.uk/v/sd/B494P_SP132_10_4D6FFc/p_mp4_400x533" type="video/mp4">          
</video>
```

Comment: I just wish I could use this solution (your template looks nice) but I just cannot. I have to use Youtube as source and they do not provide URLs to mp4 (or any other media type).

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you-tube had a HTML5 version you could use, though it's been a while since I played with it...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/C0DPdy98e4c?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" width="400" height="300">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/C0DPdy98e4c?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" />
</object>
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work, I got just a transparent box where the video should be.

Answer (score 0):

This will work until mid 2017 when they ban active content. Replace Xs with 11 digit code on the page.

```
<OBJECT width=740 height=400><PARAM NAME="movie"VALUE="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXXXXXX?rel=0&hd=0"><PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="opaque">
```